# Prawn pdf attachments in the email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

In my Rails application, I'm trying to attach the invoice to the email:

```
def invoice(invoice)
  attachment :content_disposition => "attachment",
             :body => InvoicePdf.new(invoice),
             :content_type => "application/pdf",
             :filename => 'invoice.pdf'

  mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "Your Invoice")
end
```

The **InvoicePdf** is a Prawn PDF document:

```
class InvoicePdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(order, view)
    draw_pdf
  end

  def draw_pdf
    # pdf stuff
  end
end
```

I get no attachments in the email.  What am I doing wrong?  Any tips would be welcomed and appreciated.

**Edit:** The Rails version I'm using is **3.0.x**

Comment: what rails version is your app using?

Comment: Rails 3.0.15. Updating the ticket now

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at the [Action Mailer Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-with-attachments). You need to call the attachments method for you to add an attachment.

Try this:

```
attachments['attachment_filename'] = InvoicePdf.new(invoice)
```

This is assuming that calling InvoicePdf.new(invoice) generates a file and returns an IO object representing that file. I also noticed that your InvoicePdf class initializer expects two parameters but you are passing only one.

**Update:**
Also note that Action Mailer will take the file name and work out the mime type, set the Content-Type, Content-Disposition, Content-Transfer-Encoding and base64 encode the contents of the attachment all for you so setting it manually isn't necessary unless you want to override the defaults.

Based on your pdf generation method, this will probably be better:

```
invoice = InvoicePdf.new(invoice)
attachments["invoice.pdf"] = { :mime_type => 'application/pdf', :content => invoice.render }
mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "Your Invoice")
```

Comment: Would you know by any chance how to convert PDF object into the IO object?

Comment: Assuming your InvoicePdf class generates a pdf on the filesystem say your rails tmp directory and returns the file path you'd simply do `attachments['invoice.pdf'] = File.read(InvoicePdf.new(invoice))`

Comment: Yep something like this solves it: `attachments['invoice.pdf'] = File.read(InvoicePdf.new(invoice).render_file("invoice.pdf"))`

Comment: Glad that worked, I also just updated my answer based on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt this just

```
attachments["invoice.pdf"] = InvoicePdf.new(invoice)
```

since 3.0?

Comment: Hihi, kibyegn beat me by 1 min :-)